# Can subscribe handle all http errors?

Tags: angular, http, angular6

I have read the Angular Documentation about handling errors, but I wanted to get some clarification.

I make several http requests and then subscribe and handle the errors with subscribe. I was just wondering if this will handle all errors?

I do something like this:

```
this._apiService.dataMeta(id).subscribe((information: any) => { //subscribe to the returned data
    if (information.data.length != 0) {
        //do something with information
    } else {
        this.UserData['Error1'] = user;
    }

},
    error => {
        if(error.status == '401 '|| error.status == '400'){
            this.router.navigate(['/results'])
            this._dataService.saveApiError();
        }
        else{
            this.UserData['Error1'] = user;
        }
    }
```

The idea is that I make the request to the API. When no data is returned it gives an empty object so that is why I check the length. On `error` I first to check if it is a 400 or 401 error and act accordingly. If it is I navigate elsewhere, and if it does not I want to simply store something in an array and check that array later on.

I basically just want to make sure that this setup would handle all errors received from the HTTP request? It handles the 401 and 400 nicely, but I do not have a method for testing all other possible errors.

Comment: Yes, errors cause the error callback to be called, whatever the error is.

Comment: Okay thank you. I just wanted to clarify that this would work okay.

Comment: Actually it depends on what your _apiService does. I’m assuming it returns an unmodified Observable from the Angular HttpService, if so then it should be fine. However, it’s worth considering using RxJS, Angular have some great examples of how to handle http requests with Observable pipes, including how to catch and handle errors - https://angular.io/guide/http.